# php preg_replace help please, remove all instances of multiple words and single chars

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following

```
$search_keywords = preg_replace('/\s{1,}(and\s*)*/', ' ', $search_keywords);
```

which removes the word "and" and any extra spaces from $search_keywords

but when i try and add other words to remove like so

```
$search_keywords = preg_replace('/\s{1,}(and|with\s*)*/', ' ', $search_keywords);
```

any string with and in it it will remove the word but not the extra space, but it will remove the word "with" and the space if found in the string?

i also tried the following

```
$search_keywords = preg_replace('/\s{1,}(and\s*)(with\s*)*/', ' ', $search_keywords);
```

but that worked only for the word "and" but didn't remove the word "with" if present.

so what i am trying to do is remove all instances of the words "and" and "with" from my varible and remove any extra spaces that may leave.

Also i'd like to remove all single characters from the string which appear on their own ie:
" a "," i "," £ "," ? " etc "any" single char that appears on its own (surrounded by spaces)

so lets say my string is:
**"do u want steak and chips with a asparagus sauce?"**

I want to be able to have the following returned:
**"do want steak chips asparagus sauce"**

therefor it has removed the words **with** and **and** as well as the single char **u** ,**a** and **?**

hope that makes sence?

appreciate any help
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can correct your regex using:

```
$search_keywords = preg_replace('/\s+(\S(\s|$)|((and|with)\s*(\S\s+)?)+)/i', ' ', $search_keywords);
```

Your regex `(and|with\s*)` will allow 0 or more spaces after `with`.

[**Working Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/gE6cR9/2)

Comment: that's great thank you mate! don't suppose you know how to add a clause to remove all single characters too (a,i,?,1 etc)? thanks

Comment: So you want to remove any single characters after a space or something else?

Comment: any single char that is on its own (surrounded by a space) for example " i " thanks

Comment: ok that removes the single char and the words in the preg_replace but also removes other words which i dont want removing? so my string is "Steak With And With Chips I" and the updated code returns "Steak" where as i want it to return "steak chips" any ideas? also the single char to be removed can be !,£,? etc not just letters :) cheers

Comment: As much as like to help posters I hate changing requirements in comments section. Please update your question with clear examples and I will tweak my answer accordingly.

Comment: its almost there mate, you demo still shows the second word "u" which being a single char surrounded by spaces i dont want it included in the result, plus if i add in other single chars they also show up, even tho the "i" in the demo doesnt? really appreciate your effort and hard work!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$search_keywords = preg_replace(array('/\s{1,}(and\s*)*/','/\s{1,}(with\s*)*/'), ' ', $search_keywords);
```

Comment: A little explanation would be nice.